# All the payment methods not returning in BigCommerce Get Accepted Payment method rest api

Tags: bigcommerce, bigcommerce-checkout-sdk

I am using [BigCommerce Rest API](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference) in my React Native application to create an eCommerce app for a BigCommerce site. I am doing all the functionalities like getting products, creating a cart, creating checkout, etc, using BigCommerce rest API.

Now, there is an API to get all the accepted payment methods for checkout.
Api : https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/store-management/payment-processing/accepted-methods/paymentsmethodsget

So, when I am calling this API with all the required parameters and headers, I am getting only one payment method in the response. However, I have set up many other payment method options from the admin.

There is another API [Get All Payment method](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/store-management/payment-methods-api/payment-methods/getpaymentsmethods), which returns all the payment methods that I have set up. But returned payment method data does not contain `payment method id`. I need a payment method id to pass it on next step.

Please anyone knows how to get all the accepted payment methods with it's id in BigCommerce rest API?

Comment: Hi there, what you've explained here sounds correct. Re: Get Payments Method with order_id returns accepted methods, whereas All Payment Methods show which methods you have set up in admin. That is expected. Are you looking to see why some of your methods aren't accepted?

Comment: Yes. I have set up Paypal, COD and Stipe method on admin panel. But API only returning Stripe as accepted payment method.

Comment: Which checkout are you using, redirected or embedded?

Comment: I am using embedded checkout.

Answer (score 0):

It's to my belief that this is working as expected. The v3/payments/methods returns only a list of providers that are supported by our public payments api. This list does not include COD, so that's why that one is missing. You likely don’t see Paypal because it is Paypal Commerce Platform, which is also not expected to be returned.

As a note, this endpoint is tied to an order so if certain providers have restrictions on order total or products or things like that, they might appear/or not appear depending on those values.